# Hide keyboard upon tapping on radio button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find a way to dismiss the keyboard upon tapping on the radio buttons. I found some answers like this tutorial (https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/) but this will only hide the keyboard upon clicking outside the text field on an empty spot not tapping the radio button.

Here is a simple code if you would like to try. Any thoughts will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter { lafayette, jefferson }

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  SingingCharacter _character = SingingCharacter.lafayette;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          autofocus: true,
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Lafayette'),
          leading: Radio(
            value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
            groupValue: _character,
            onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
              setState(() {
                _character = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Thomas Jefferson'),
          leading: Radio(
            value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
            groupValue: _character,
            onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
              setState(() {
                _character = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in onChange Function write this line of code FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Answer (score 0):

A couple of Solutions

1. Using `SystemChannels`

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
   SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
   ```
2. Using `FocusScope`

   ```
   FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in onChange Function

```
 FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```